# Jar file can open only one time after download to cache

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a problem with a .jar file located on a server. I'm using the JNLP protocol to open it.  
When I open the .jnlp file for the first time, the jar file is downloaded to the browser's cache and the application runs wih no problems, but when I try to open .jnlp file again (with the jar file already in the cache), the application fails to open and this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at.com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
        at.com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at.com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
        at.com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at.java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I didn't specify the codebase in jnlp file.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).   Invalid JNLP files will be parsed in unpredictable ways by the various Java Web Start clients (that launch JWS apps.).